# Rest api - MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server

Tags: mongodb, rest, express

I'm trying to create a simple rest api to a mongo db

I have a server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-Parser');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

const db = require('./config/keys').mongoURI;

mongoose
    .connect('mongodb://test:test123@ds241012.mlab.com:41012/test_db' ,{useNewUrlParser: true})
    .then(() => console.log('DB Connected'))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log('Server started'));
```

I using nodemon, when I do npm run server I get 'Server started' in the terminal (the console.log)

after this I get the follwoing output the terminal

```
{ MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [ds241012.mlab.com:41012] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connection 0 to ds241012.mlab.com:41012 timed out]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/Users/cdd/Documents/_Work/cd/React/test_db/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:564:11)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/Users/cdd/Documents/_Work/cd/React/test_db/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:317:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:317:30)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/Users/cdd/Documents/_Work/cd/React/test_db/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:257:10)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
    at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at Socket._onTimeout (net.js:420:8)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:482:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:317:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:277:5)
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

If I then update the server.js the terminal returns to 'Server started'

Is it normal to gte this output

Answer (score 0):

If you have already whitelisted the IP address of machine from which you are trying to connect mongodb then the only possibility because of which you are getting the error is because the firewall is blocking it.